# React Native - How to hide splash screen when all components have been been rendered inside it?

Tags: firebase, react-native

I have a function which fetches data from firebase, `SplashScreen.hide()` is called when fetching is done and states are set. The problem is, when `SplashScreen.hide()` is called, the components are still loading for 1 - 2 seconds before they appear, is there a better way of ensuring that the components are already rendered? The items being rendered are dependent on the state `cardComponents`, which when set will render the cards.

P.S. I'm using `react-native-splash-screen`

```
fetchCards = () => {
    let cardRef = firebase.firestore().collection('tblcard')
    let itemRef = firebase.firestore().collection('tblitem')
    let cards = []
    let items = []
    let cardComponents = []
    let today = new Date()
    today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)

    cardRef.where('date', '=', today).get().then(function(cardSnapshot) {
      cardSnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        cards[doc.id] = doc.data()
      })

      itemRef.get().then(function(itemSnapshot) {
        itemSnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
          items[doc.id] = doc.data()
        })

        cards.forEach(function(card, index) {
          let id = index
          let item1 = items[card.item1]
          let item2 = items[card.item2]
          let question = card.question.replace('?', ',') + '\n' + item1.item_name + ' o ' + item2.item_name + '?'

          cardComponents.push({id: id, image1: item1.image_url, image2: item2.image_url, question: question})
        })

        this.setState({cardComponents: cardComponents})
        this.setState({cards: cards})
        this.setState({items: items})

        SplashScreen.hide()
      }.bind(this))
    }.bind(this))
}

render () {
  {this.state.cardComponents}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because calling `setState` is asynchronous by nature. So when `SplashScreen.hide()` after setting your state, your state has not been properly updated yet. You have 2 options:

Use the lifecycle method componentDidUpdate to detect that your state has been updated:

```
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevState.cardComponents !== this.state.cardComponents) {
      SplashScreen.hide();
    }
  }
```

Use the callback offered in the `setState` method:

```
this.setState({cardComponents: cardComponents}, () => { SplashScreen.hide(); })
```